# Mongodb Java driver use limit in aggregation query

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

**Problem**

Query is working fine but not limit and skip, it is fetching all records at once.

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

**MongoDB Collection**

```
 {  
      "_id" : ObjectId("559666c4e4b07a176940c94f"),     
      "postId" : "559542b1e4b0108c9b6f390e",    
     "user" : {         
                 "userId" : "5596598ce4b07a176940c943",         
                 "displayName" : "User1",       
                 "username" : "user1",      
                 "image" : ""   
      },    
      "postFor" : {         
                     "type": "none",
                      "typeId" : ""     
      },    
     "actionType" : "like",     
     "isActive" : 1,
     "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-07-03T10:41:07.575Z"),   
     "updatedDate" : ISODate("2015-07-03T10:41:07.575Z") 
}
```

**Java driver Query**

```
 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(                                

      match(Criteria.where("isActive").is(1).and("user.userId").in(feedUsers)),
      group("postId")
      .last("postId").as("postId")
      .last("postFor").as("postFor")
      .last("actionType").as("actionType")
      .last("isActive").as("isActive")
      .last("user").as("user")
      .last("createdDate").as("createdDate")
      .last("updatedDate").as("updatedDate"),
      sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate")
    );
aggregation.skip( skip );
aggregation.limit( limit );
AggregationResults<UserFeedAggregation> groupResults =
mongoOps.aggregate(aggregation, SocialActionsTrail.class, UserFeedAggregation.class);
return groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregation pipelines are "sequential" in operation. These are not like `.find()` operations where `.sort()` `.limit()` `.skip()` are "modifiers" to the query operation:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(                               
    match(Criteria.where("isActive")
        .is(1).and("user.userId").in(feedUsers)),
    group("postId")
        .last("postId").as("postId")
        .last("postFor").as("postFor")
        .last("actionType").as("actionType")
        .last("isActive").as("isActive")
        .last("user").as("user")
        .last("createdDate").as("createdDate")
        .last("updatedDate").as("updatedDate"),
    sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate"),
    skip( skip ),
    limit( limit )
);
```

Unless you define the operations in "sequence" then the pipeline does not know the order of execution. So define the pipeline as a whole.

---

A basic example:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    group("postId"),
    skip(1),
    limit(1)
);

System.out.println(aggregation)
```

Outputs a perfect pipeline:

```
{ 
    "aggregate" : "__collection__" ,
    "pipeline" : [ 
        { "$group" : { "_id" : "$postId" } },
        { "$skip" : 1 },
        { "$limit" : 1 }
    ]
}
```

See [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in the core documentation.

Comment: I tried it. I got error 
- The method skip(int) is undefined

Comment: @Rajnishkatiyar-SIPL So the variable for `skip` is undefined! Surely that should be a clear error. The point I am making is that your basic calling sequence was incorrect.

Comment: I can assure you that is not an issue because I have tried like this also- skip( 0 ), limit( 5 )

Comment: @Rajnishkatiyar-SIPL You need to take more than a few seconds to response. Run the code. `.skip(0)` does not result in "undefined".

Comment: @BlakesSeven you are right in that, but mongodb java spring driver dont have skip and limit method like sort and group. I also have same problem with skip and limit function with aggregation.

Comment: @AjayKurmi you need to ask your own question. But if you read the answer and the addition I just gave then you might learn something from there.

Comment: @Rajnishkatiyar-SIPL Don't know how I can make it clearer than the short example I have added to the answer. If you have other errors then the fault is in other areas of your code. My pipeline construction is correct.